# Getting ModelValidationException when accepting Option<List<String> as query parameter

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am getting ModelValidationException when I write endpoint as below

```
@GET
public void foo(@QueryParam("values") Optional<List<String>> values, @QueryParam("page") Optional<Integer> page)
```

but this works

```
@GET
public void foo(@NotNull @QueryParam("values") List<String> values, @QueryParam("page") Optional<Integer> page)
```

is `Optional<List<String>>` not allowed as a query parameter? 
other optional types like `Optional<String>` or `Optional<Integer` work fine.

Comment: List will be empty if query param is not set, why it's needed

Comment: Do you mean it will be an empty ArrayList? or it'll be null?